# WPF ListView using both ItemTemplate and GridViewColumn.. is it possible?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, listview

I have a requirement where I have a listview which is bound to a collection by making use of GridViewColumn. But I have a requirement where based on certain selected value in a column, I modify the item template of the listview.

Meaning the listview is made of only one row, the item template should get modified. Is it possible by any chance.

```
<Window x:Class="ListViewSample.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:ListViewSample"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525"
    >
<Window.Resources>
    <local:ListViewConverter x:Key="listViewConverter"/>
    <DataTemplate x:Key="doubleRowListViewItem">
        <Grid>                
            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <TextBlock Background="YellowGreen" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0"/>
            <TextBlock Background="GreenYellow" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0" />                
        </Grid>
    </DataTemplate>
</Window.Resources>
<Grid>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <ListView Grid.Row="1" ItemsSource="{Binding Persons}" >            
        <ListView.View>
            <GridView>                    
                <GridViewColumn Header="Country" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Country}"/>
                <GridViewColumn Header="Name" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Name}"/>
            </GridView>
        </ListView.View>
    </ListView>
</Grid>
</Window>
```

here once the value of the country is set to a particular entry the item template should change accordingly. The item template should be set to the data template declared above.

Is there any way to achieve this.

thanks.
Sandeep

Comment: you could use [Trigger](http://wpftutorial.net/Triggers.html)

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what you are looking for, but if you want a visual dynamic Row, you can drop the `DisplayMemberBinding` and use [CellTemplate](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.gridviewcolumn.celltemplate.aspx). You can modify that CellTemplate or multiple CellTemplates via Triggers like you could with any other Template.